# Can we access component variable in routing module in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

We are using multi language for our application. So we need to change the language from when entering localhost to localhost/en .So if i change the language in URL need to effect in all the menu lists. How can we achieve this in Angular 5?

Comment: please add to code to show what you have done so far.

Comment: pass it as url param.

Answer (score 0):

On Angular 4 (I think that works even on Angular 5) you can set language value into data property:

app.component.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';

@Component({ 
    template: `
    <h1>Angular Router</h1>
    <nav> <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active"> Home </a>
          <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active"> About </a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> `
})

export class AppComponent {}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: "home", component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full", data: { language: "en"},
                children:
                [ 
                    { path: "it", component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full", data: { language: "en"},
                    { path: "de", component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full", data: { language: "en"}
                ]
            },
            { path: "about", component: AboutComponent,
        ])
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

For read data property into your home component you can use ActivatedRoute.snapshot to extract the route parameters:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent{
    
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)
    {
        // Read the data property
        let languageValue = this.route.snapshot.params['language'];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have included as language component

And rerouting done in router.module by accessing this language component as parent module.